# What's the relationship between Apache spark and Map reduce

Tags: shell, mapreduce, apache-spark

I've got some questions about the Spark framework.

First, if I want to write some applications that runs on spark clusters, is it unavoidable to follow the map-reduce procedure? Since to follow the map-reduce procedure, lots of codes has to be changed to parallelize forms, I'm looking for some simple way to move current project to cluster with little changes in codes.

Second is about the spark-shell. I've tried to launch the spark-shell on a cluster using the following code: `MASTER=spark://IP:PORT ./bin/spark-shell`. Then I write some scala codes on the spark-shell,for example:

```
var count1=0
var ntimes=10000
var index=0
while(index<ntimes)
{
index+=1
val t1 = Math.random()
val t2 = Math.random()
if (t1*t1 + t2*t2 < 1) 
        count1+=1
}
var pi= 4.0 * count1 / ntimes

val count2 = spark.parallelize(1 to NUM_SAMPLES).map{i =>
  val x = Math.random()
  val y = Math.random()
  if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
}.reduce(_ + _)
println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count2 / NUM_SAMPLES)
```

These codes contain two different Pi caculation programs. I'm wandering whether all of these codes runs on the cluster. I guess that only these codes surrounded by the map{} function are executed on cluster while other codes only executed on the master node. but I'm not sure whether that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark provides a more generic framework than simply Map & Reduce.  If you examine the [API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations) you can find quite a few other functions that are more generic, such as aggregate.  In addition, Spark supports features such as broadcast variables and accumulators that make parallel programming much more effective.

The second question (you really should separate the two):
Yes, the two codes are executed differently.  If you want to take advantage of Spark's parallel capabilities, you have to use the RDD data structures.  Until you understand how the RDD is distributed and how operations affect the RDD, it will be difficult to use Spark effectively.

Any code that is not executing in an method over an RDD is not parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. They are very useful for a beginner like me to study the spark framework.